Maintaining secrets in Azure Key Vault so that we can limit individual access
I’m trying to understand the best practices around maintaining secrets in key vaults:

Question 1: Should we give infrastructure access to Azure Key Vault and have the team member access to maintain the secrets?

Question 2: Second options is to have a script that would read the values from ADO variable group and then the script would add/update them into the key vault.


I was trying to implement the second option so that we can have all the secrets managed from a single place and this is what happens.
The plan was to have those variables that are supposed to be in KeyVault start with the static string KeyVault_ and then read those using the az pipeline variable group show -- group-id $GROUP_ID but as expected the value is empty for secrets values.
How can I achieve a similar approach and update the key vault secrets from ADO secrets.
$variable_group.variables.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.Key.StartsWith("KeyVault_")) {
        $SecretName = $_.Key -replace "KeyVault_", ""
        $SecretValue = $_.Value.value

        if ($SecretValue) {
            Write-Output "Creating secret for $SecretName."
            az keyvault secret set --vault-name $KeyVaultName --name $SecretName --value $SecretValue --output none
            Write-Output "Added secret '$SecretName' to Key Vault '$KeyVaultName'."
        } else {
            Write-Warning "No value found for variable '$($_.Key)'."
        }
    }
}

How can I get the value for $SecretValue assigned properly, I've tried $($_.Key) but with no luck!

In the Azure DevOps project where the variable group is in, you can set up 2 YAML pipelines (ListVars and UpdateSecrets) like as below:


The PowerShell script "scripts/list-variabe-names.ps1".
param (
    # Name of Azure DevOps organization.
    [Alias("org", "o")]
    [string] $organization,

    # Name of project where the variable group and pipelines are in.
    [Alias("proj", "p")]
    [string] $project,

    # ID of variable group.
    [Alias("gid")]
    [string] $groupId,

    # ID of the pipeline (UpdateSecrets) that needs to be triggered by this script.
    [Alias("pid")]
    [string] $PipelineId,

    # Name of Azure Key Vault.
    [Alias("kv")]
    [string] $keyVault
)

$response = (az pipelines variable-group variable list --org "https://dev.azure.com/$organization" -p "$project" --id $groupId | ConvertFrom-Json)
$varNames = $response | Get-Member | Where {$_. MemberType -like 'NoteProperty'} | Select-Object -Property name

$varNamesList = "["
ForEach ($varName in $varNames.Name)
{
    $varNamesList += "${varName},"
}

$varNamesList = $varNamesList -replace ".{1}$"
$varNamesList += "]"

az pipelines run --org "https://dev.azure.com/$organization" -p "$project" --id $PipelineId --parameters variableNames="$varNamesList" KeyVaultName="$keyVault"


The first pipeline (ListVars).
# list-variable-group-variables.yml

trigger: none

# When manually triggering this pipeline,
# you can enter new values to override the default values of parameters.
parameters:
- name: organizationName
  type: string
  default: 'myOrg'

- name: projectName
  type: string
  default: 'myProj'

- name: groupId
  type: number
  default: 5

- name: PipelineId
  type: number
  default: 83

- name: KeyVaultName
  type: string
  default: 'myKV'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    filePath: 'scripts/list-variabe-names.ps1'
    arguments: >
      -o "${{ parameters.organizationName }}"
      -p "${{ parameters.projectName }}"
      -gid ${{ parameters.groupId }}
      -pid ${{ parameters.PipelineId }}
      -kv "${{ parameters.KeyVaultName }}"



The second pipeline (UpdateSecrets).
# update-secrets.yml

trigger: none

parameters:
- name: variableNames
  type: object
  default: []

- name: KeyVaultName
  type: string
  default: ''

variables:
- group: myVarGroup

steps:
- ${{ each variableName in parameters.variableNames }}:  
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'Set KeyVault secret - ${{ variableName }}'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'myArmConnection'
      scriptType: 'pscore'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        Write-Host "Setting Azure Key Vault secret - ${{ variableName }}"
        az keyvault secret set --vault-name ${{ parameters.KeyVaultName }} --name ${{ variableName }} --value $(${{ variableName }})


On the Security hub of Pipelines, ensure the build identities "Project Collection Build Service ({Organization-Name})" and "{Project-Name} Build Service ({Organization-Name})" have the following permissions set to "Allow".

Queue builds
Edit queue build configuration




With above configurations, when you manually trigger the first pipeline (ListVars) with your values of parameters, the pipeline will execute the PowerShell script "scripts/list-variabe-names.ps1" to do the following things.

Call the Azure DevOps CLI "az pipelines variable-group variable list" to list all variables from the variable group. And pick up the variable names into a list.
Call CLI "az pipelines run" to trigger the second pipeline (UpdateSecrets) and pass the required parameter values to it.

When the second pipeline is triggered, it receives the parameter values passed from the first pipeline, and then use the values to run the Azure CLI "az keyvault secret set" to set or update secret with the new secret value into Azure Key Vault.


That was clever, thank you @Bright Ran-MSFT

It's best to link your Azure DevOps variable groups to Key Vault as detailed in https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/library/link-variable-groups-to-key-vaults?view=azure-devops. You should also create separate vaults for different projects because they are relatively cheap - practically free depending on use, which DevOps is unlikely to surpass.
Yes, you should give trusted members access to update secrets as needed, but it's best to manage these members assigned to a role using RBAC instead of legacy access policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli. This gives them access to update or otherwise rotate secrets.
It's really just shifting the problem by giving people access to a DevOps variable group to set these in Key Vault. At some point, a set of individuals has to be trusted to set or even view resources. But Key Vault gives you better protection and auditing than DevOps variable groups.
Note: if you are using secrets to secure access between services in Azure, it's actually best you use managed identity whenever possible.

IMO you should use Key Vault to manage the secrets and link the variable groups to secrets in Azure Key Vault.
A Variable group has limited functionality and scope as compared to Azure Key Vault.
Azure Key Vault provides centralized secrets management, with full control over access policies and audit history. It supports secrets rotation and versioning to ensure that secrets can be regularly updated without causing disruptions to your automated processes. You can also monitor the vaults/secrets and implement alerting, e.g. when an item is about to expire.
